# Irreversible Migrations - warning & confirm instead of abort?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, associations

I've been writing some migrations lately which fall under the Irreversible Migration umbrella. But they aren't end of the world irreversible. You could roll them back if you want. The scenario I have at the moment is changing a one to many relationship to a many to many relationship. It involves dropping a column and making a new join table. (as well as two lines in the models).

I was thinking, instead of aborting the down migration, I could say something like "This migration is [INSERT SCARY MESSAGE HERE], are you sure you want to proceed? Y/N" and then roll back the migration if they choose to? Just put the migration inside an if statement?

It's easy enough to make migrations irreversible, and usually there's good reason (e.g. data can't be recovered). Do these issues usually get resolved by just writing a migration which does it manually?

In my noobish mind it'd be nice to have a happy medium. Is it wise? Maybe I just don't understand when to make them non-reversible in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always try to make the migration reversible if possible. The only time I think I've run into problems is when you go from a coarsely defined data model to a finer grained on, and then back again. I don't see any reason to not use your solution though, depending of course, on the consequences of the migration. There is also nothing stopping the person running the down migration from commenting out your raised error and writing their own code to reverse the migration, but it is far safer for you, the person writing the data model change to know how to transform back to the previous state instead of them guessing.

Comment: "It is far safer for you, the person writing the data model change to know how to transform back to the previous state instead of them guessing". Exactly! That's why I was slightly surprised this option wasn't available already - as it's entirely possible someone will just override the exception you write.

Comment: Ruby has very few rules. consider: http://gfredericks.com/gfrlog/post/51
So, we rely on common sense, convention, and good testing :)

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled over this old post here - as I struggled somehow over the same question.

I had the other case: moving from many-to-many (HABTM) to one-to-many. Of course, I wanted to delete the join table afterwards. I was really afraid that I would forget to copy over the data from the join table during deployment. So I decided to include a "warning" migration:

```
class DataMigrationWarning < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    puts("********************** Data Migration Warning **********************")
    puts("Dont forgett to save the data.")
    puts("Next UP migration will delete table XYZ.")
    puts("Next DOWN migration will delete field A in table BCD.")
    puts("press y for continue.")
    puts("press anything else for stopping.")

    if STDIN.gets.chomp == "y"
        puts("Ok then!")
    else
        fail
    end

    # More detailed explanation...

  end
end
```

The command line will then just show all the things in there and waits for an input from the user. y will just go to next migration. all other inputs will stop the migration and all following.

The process looked in the end like:

1. Migration: Create new field for new belong_to
2. Warning migration
3. Migration: Delete old join table

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Nothing like a huge warning to make things serious. Thanks!